# How to execute code before or after a crud event

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to learn Java Spring framework. I have been following some books and guides however they are all the standard ToDo ( HelloWorld ) type applications.

One topic that has commonly been untouched in the guides I have been following is how to update other system records upon the execution of crud operations of an entirely different (however usually related) record.

Here is a contrived example.

I have an object `ToDo` which is persisted in the database. I also have another object `ToDoDailyReport` which is persisted in the database ( ignore the fact that this could probably be calculated on the fly ).

If I execute any crud operation on a `ToDo` I would like to update the `ToDoDailyReport`

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` and creating `CrudRepositories` annotating them with `@RepositoryRestResource` similar to this example ( [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) )

In my mind I imagine I could create a bunch of custom controllers using `@RestController` and implement whatever behaviour I want however I like the idea of leaving their CrudRepositories as is and simply executing a function before or after the crud operation is fired. I have seen discussion of `AOP` and `AspectJ` however I am not sure if these approaches are meant for my use case or what approach I should be implementing and how I would fire a `AOP advice` before or after the crud operation.

Any advice or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to Spring Boot, so whether or not this is the correct approach to solve this problem will remain to be seen however the question

"How to execute code before or after a crud event"

Is answered by using events which are fired by the REST exporter during CRUD operations.

[Documentation can be found here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events)