# Using Spring application events, how can I order EventListeners listening for different events in the same class?

Tags: java, spring, event-listener

I know Spring has an `@Order` annotation to control the order `EventListeners` listening for the same event are invoked. For example:

```
public class A {

    @EventListener
    @Order(0)
    public void doFirstThing(SomeEvent event) {
    }
}

public class B {

    @EventListener
    @Order(1)
    public void doSecondThing(SomeEvent event) {
    }
}
```

I have a class with multiple `EventListeners` listening for different events. How can I control the order these listeners are invoked?

```
public class A {

    @EventListener
    public void doFirstThing(SomeEvent event) {
    }

    @EventListener
    public void doSecondThing(DifferentEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Kate, I am new to Spring. This is a bit of a tangent from your question so I apologise for that. I have been trying to gather an understanding of how "related" data should be updated in Spring Before / After CRUD operations. I wonder if you would not mind commenting on my question to help me geta better grasp of how Spring works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222077/updating-other-application-data-on-crud-operations

Comment: I have not started looking into events yet although they are on my radar as I think Events, AOP, AspectJ are how I am going to resolve my question. If I find something related to your question I will try to help.